# Binding Window Title through Style && triggers in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, triggers, styles

I've code like that

```
<Window x:Class="SolutionName.ClassName"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="300" Width="300" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ItemKind}" Value="SomeKind">
                <Setter Property="Title" Value="SomeTitle"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ItemKind}" Value="SomeKind2">
                <Setter Property="Title" Value="SomeTitle"/>
            </DataTrigger>
```

I want is to change window title depending on a property *ItemKind* implemented in the viewmodel (set as datacontext). The code above won't work and I'm really confused because can't find any mistakes.

Comment: do u see any binding errors in the Output window?

Comment: Did you set the Title elsewhere?

Comment: Is ItemKind an Enum? Afair then the Value must be written with value path syntax, or you need to write a Type converter. So instead of Value="SomeKind" use <DataTrigger.Value><MyEnum>SomeKind</MyEnum>...

Comment: The example code doesn't show this, but any chance you have a databinding set up for `Title`? If so, this will override your trigger. That's what the problem ended up being for me; I worked around it by setting `Title` in the style with the databinding in `Setter.Value`, then overriding it with triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seems fine and working at my end. Have you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your ViewModel class. You need to implement it to so as to propagate any change in property value in your ViewModel class to reflect back on your UI.

[How to: Implement Property Change Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)